# Tell shiny I am talking about a data frame column name not a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dashboard, geom-sf

So I am trying to create a shiny app in which I am plotting a map of India using sf data.
I have uploaded a dataset which has multiple columns.
So I ask the use to select the column. But when I gave that input to `geom_sf(fill = input$select_topic)` It firstly thinks the column name is a single char value, so I use `geom_sf(fill = .data$input$select_topic)` or `geom_sf(fill = ,data[[input$select_topic]] )` which gives me
**`error : Can't subset .data outside of a data mask context.`**

here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)


# joining the main datset and the sf dataset 

map_data <- read.csv("D:\\R Projects\\R experimental\\dashboard\\app-1\\app-1\\data\\edu_data.csv")
map_data <- as.data.frame(map_data)
map_data_2 <- left_join(India, map_data, by = "state_ut")


# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My Shiny App"),
  
  sidebarLayout(position = "right",
    sidebarPanel(
      
      selectInput("select_year", label = "Select Year", 
                  choices = list("2012-13" = 2012,
                                 "2013-14" = 2013, 
                                 "2014-15" = 2014,
                                 "2015-16" = 2015), selected = 2013),
      selectInput("select_topic", label = "Select Category", 
                  choices = list("Drinking Water Facility" = 'water_faci', 
                                 "Girl's Toilet Facility" = 'gtoi_faci',
                                 "Boy's Toilet Facility" = 'btoi_faci',
                                 "Electricity Connection" = 'elec_faci',
                                 "Computer availability" = 'comp_faci',
                                 "Overall Facilities" = 'all_faci',
                                 "Gross Enrollment" = 'gross_enroll',
                                 "Drop-out Rate" = 'drop_rate' 
                                 ), selected = "Drinking Water Facility")
      
    mainPanel(
      h1("Maps"),
      textOutput("selected_year"),
      textOutput("selected_category"),
      plotOutput("map")
      )
  )
  
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$selected_year <- renderText({
    paste("You have selected the year:", input$select_year)
  })
  
  
  output$selected_category <- renderText({
    paste("You have selected category:", input$select_topic)
  })
  
  })
  output$map <- renderPlot({
    x <- map_data_2 %>% filter(., year == input$select_year)
    
    ggplot(x, aes(label = state_ut)) +
      geom_sf( fill = .data$input$select_topic ) +
      scale_fill_distiller(palette = "GnBu", 
                           direction= 1, 
                           na.value="grey") +
      theme_map() + 
      theme( plot.title = element_text(size=22), 
             legend.position = "left", 
             legend.justification ='left') 
  })  
  
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Here is the dataset whose column I need to select**

| state_ut | year | water_faci | comp_faci | btoi_faci | gtoi_faci | elec_faci | all_faci | gross_enroll | drop_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All India | 2013 | 95.4 | 24.08 | 86.56 | 91.23 | 56.78 | 70.81 | 79.89 | 6.88 |
| Andaman & Nicobar Islands | 2013 | 98.69 | 53.06 | 94.52 | 93.44 | 88.86 | 85.714 | 96.8 | 6.2 |
| Andhra Pradesh | 2013 | 90.35 | 29.57 | 56.88 | 81.31 | 90.34 | 69.69 | 78.95 | 8.14 |
| Arunachal Pradesh | 2013 | 79.79 | 24.28 | 48.73 | 76.9 | 36.35 | 53.21 | 98.58 |  |
| Assam | 2013 | 80.3 | 8.85 | 60.17 | 75.28 | 19.39 | 48.798 | 77.68 | 13.04 |
| Bihar | 2013 | 92.53 | 5.47 | 73.42 | 75.41 | 9.96 | 51.358 | 67.24 |  |
| Chandigarh | 2013 | 100 | 95.83 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 99.166 | 94.18 |  |
| Chhattisgarh | 2013 | 95.47 | 9.8 | 82.85 | 94.1 | 57.28 | 67.9 | 89.98 |  |

```
output$map <- renderPlot({
    x <- map_data_2 %>% filter(., year == input$select_year)

    ggplot(x, aes(label = state_ut)) +
      geom_sf( fill = input$select_topic ) +
      scale_fill_distiller(palette = "GnBu", 
                           direction= 1, 
                           na.value="grey") +
      theme_map() + 
      theme( plot.title = element_text(size=22), 
             legend.position = "left", 
             legend.justification ='left') 
  })
```

will result in a  map which has taken the fill values as a column present in the dataset.

Comment: Could you create a very minimal example that requires minimal packages?

Comment: Try using `fill = !!sym(input$select_topic)`

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Yes but it gives an error: invalid argument type

Comment: See https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html#using-aes-and-vars-in-a-package-function-1 for the use of `fill = .data[[input$select_topic]]`. One could also use [`aes_`](https://ggplot2-book.org/programming.html#indirectly-referring-to-variables)`(fill=input$select_topic)`, but `aes_` is deprecated so I suggest going the other route first.

Comment: FYI, that first fill should be within aes, as in `aes(fill=.data[[input$select_topic]])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `fill=` in two ways:

- put it within `aes(.)`, and
- use `.data[[ input$select_year ]]`. (The use of `.data$input$select_year` cannot work.)

```r
output$map <- renderPlot({
    x <- map_data_2 %>% filter(., year == input$select_year)

    ggplot(x, aes(label = state_ut)) +
      geom_sf(aes(fill = .data[[ input$select_topic ]])) +
      scale_fill_distiller(palette = "GnBu", 
                           direction= 1, 
                           na.value="grey") +
      theme_map() + 
      theme( plot.title = element_text(size=22), 
             legend.position = "left", 
             legend.justification ='left') 
  })
```

See https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html#using-aes-and-vars-in-a-package-function-1 for how to reference column names indirectly.